# Send push notification to user at a certain time in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I would like to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) to send reminder messages to a user device, e.g. a push notification (or email) at 3 PM.
Does Firebase come with a build in option for such a use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `firebase-could-function` to send the notifications to users , and then setup cron job to trigger your function at the time you want with the period you want